# Error in JAVA code while running it

Tags: java

> targets:
>   scanning numbers (unknown ending), ends when -1 or less is written, prints the smallest number and the first 10 numbers

im trying to get this code work as a school assignment but can't get a code without errors. please help.

```
public class Sheela1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean isPrice = true;
        int i = 0;
        int[] arr = new int[10];
        int min = 0;

        while (isPrice = true) {
            System.out.println("enter num");
            int num = scan.nextInt();
            if ((num > -1) && (i <= 10)) {
                isPrice = true;
                arr[i] = num;
            } else if ((num > -1) && (i > 10)) {
                isPrice = true;
            } else if (num <= -1) {
                isPrice = false;
            }

            if ((i == 0) && (min == 0)) {
                min = num;
            } else if ((i > 0) && (num < min)) {
                min = num;
            }
            if (i < 10) {
                System.out.println("num " + (i + 1) + " " + "in the first 10: " + arr[i]);
            } else {
                System.out.println(num);
            }
            i = i + 1;
        }
        System.out.println("min: " + min);
    }
}
```

[the code in eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLuUx.png)

Comment: I see one warning and no errors.

Comment: the error occurs while the variable i reaches 10.

Comment: And the error is...?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
 at Sheela1.main(Sheela1.java:18)

Comment: @MichaelKorn, I was about to write the a good answer but they close the question, You can see this link for the answer, https://paste.ubuntu.com/26430185/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue  is `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10` because you use array and fixed the size by 10 and you try to add more than 10 elements int this array,
please read this [arrayindexoutofboundsexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it) for more details.

you have to use array list instead of array

```
 ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();

 arr.add(num); // use this  add new item to array
```